# Making new activity in Android Studio results in error every time

Tags: android, android-activity, build-error

I am amazed with the creativity of the team behind the entire Android project...
They always come up with some new and exciting ways to make our lives more miserable with introducing some horrible, horrible bugs, errors and randomness...

So, whenever l make new activity, it always ends up woth an error.

So, this is the process of making new activity:

[image]

Right after a make one, next error appears:

[image]

And now I have to go to: Project Structure - Dependencies - and remove then add com.android.support:appcompat and like, the bug is fixed?

Why the hell I have to do that every time?
Nothing happens..I just make a new activity and everything goes to hell !

Comment: Im sure this downvote came from somebody from the Android team....

Comment: You are using version 0.8.11, yes? Also i do not understand why you are ranting over issues in BETA software.

Comment: I'm ranting because they should have published ALPHA 5 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the dependency to your build.gradle file ?
Have you installed the Android Support Library with your SDK Manager ?

Comment: Yes sir..all of that is done. I'm telling you..everything works perfefctly fine, then I add new activity and have to remove / add com.android.support:appcompat

Comment: You have the Android Support Repository installed too ?